How to use input signal in service?
I have a component which gets an array as an input signal:
export class MembersComponent {
  members = input.required<Member[]>();

and a service
constructor (private service: MyService) {}

the service is provided by a parent component.
How do I pass the value of members to the service? Is this OK?
class MyService {
  members = computed(()=>[]) // will be overridden by component

Now I can set the method in the component with:
this.service.members = computed(()=>this.members());

I can do it in the constructor or in ngOnInit, but it does not satisfy me, is there a more elegant solution?

Your structure looks a bit strange, if you use the MembersComponent multiple times on the same screen, the components will keep overriding the value in the service, leading to unpredictable results. Unless you provide your service in this component, which would create a service instance per component. But I'm not sure if this works for your scenario.

@JSONDerulo made some edits plz review

@NarenMurali thanks, but I am not sure if we need untracked? In Angular 19, signal writes in effects are allowed again.

@JSONDerulo Just for safety, please modify the code for signal writes, whichever method you want

the comments have nothing to do with my question. The structure is OK.

@NarenMurali I set up a stackblitz, it works fine without untracked, so I removed it again. Thanks for the other changes!

You are overriding a computed function which is not good practice, and can lead to problems.
Instead, in your service you should have a writable signal.
In your component, you should use an effect to update this signal:
export class MembersComponent {
  members = input.required<Member[]>();

  constructor (private service: MyService) {
    effect(() => {
      this.service.members.set(this.members());
    });
  }
}

Whenever the value of the input changes, the value in the service is updated.
Also the initial value is set in the service.

Note that currently effects are in developer preview and might change before becoming stable

Also see the StackBlitz demo.

But here service.members is an array and not a signal, so ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush wont work and I lose an advantage of signals. This can't be best practice.

@Galdor check now

ERROR RuntimeError: NG0600: Writing to signals is not allowed in a computed or an effect by default. There is a workaround for this, but this can' be best practice, either.

@Galdor are you still on Angular 18? Because starting from Angular 19, this code will be allowed. In the meantime you can set allowSignalWrites: true. Also see this blog about effect: https://blog.angular.dev/latest-updates-to-effect-in-angular-f2d2648defcd I also added a StackBlitz demo which proofs that this works fine in Angular 19.
